# Как сразу сформировать XmlElement с помощью сериализаторов

Tags: c#, xml

Есть у меня такой код. Сохранение:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
var sb = new StringBuilder();

using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
{
  m_serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
}

doc.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
return new XmlRemoteTaskParameterValues(doc.DocumentElement);
```

Чтение:

```
var converted = values as XmlRemoteTaskParameterValues;

using (var reader = new StringReader(converted.Parameters.OuterXml))
{
  return m_serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Для `WCF` необходимо, чтобы свойство `XmlRemoteTaskParameterValues.Parameters` имело тип `XmlElement`. Но меня смущает лишняя операция перепаковки данных: когда я сохраняю данные, я сначала формирую строку, чтобы её распарсить и снова получить xml, когда я читаю данные, я сначала преобразую `XmlElement` в строку, чтобы потом её распарсить сериализатором.

Есть ли более эффективный способ, позволяющий замкнуть сериализатор непосредственно на `XmlDocument`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В FCL по некоторой причине [отсутствует](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/170614/missing-xmlnodewriter) такой класс, как `XmlNodeWriter`. Однако существует неплохая замена:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild()) 
{ 
    m_serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде работает. А для потокового чтения данных из `XmlElement` что-нибудь есть?

Comment: А, понятно, `XmlNodeReader`. Вроде работает. Спасибо.